# Matlab says invalid file installation key

Tags: 14.04, matlab

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to install Matlab 2015a and when I enter the installation key I get this error

> you have entered an invalid file installation key

But the key is correct .. 
please help

Comment: Wrong place to ask this ;) http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101424-why-does-the-installer-tell-me-i-have-entered-in-an-invalid-file-installation-key-when-installing-us or http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101078-why-do-i-receive-an-error-about-an-invalid-file-installlation-key-when-installing-matlab-manually-wi

Comment: Sorry, I thought its linux issue because I didn't face this problem on Windows.
Thanks.

Comment: Linux needs a different FIK than the one for windows (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Matlab, they have different installation keys for different variants of the application - a Windows key won't work for Linux, and vice versa, while known 'leaked' keys are probably no longer valid in Matlab's installer systems.  As well, an isntaller key for a different version of Matlab won't help you either (as in 2014 vs. 2015)